# How to use VSTest from Nuke builds

Tags: nuke-build

I am trying to use Nuke to run VSTest as some of my tests are in .Net Framework (not core).

I have a test running succesfully with:

```
VSTest(@".\test\MyTestProjectFolder\bin\Debug\net47\MyTestProject.dll");
```

...but I don't like to point into the bin\debug\net47 folder if I don't have to.

I would much prefer to point out the test project source, or even the solution.

Running

```
VSTest(@".\test\**\*.csproj");
```

returns an IReadOnlyCollection<Output> containing 9 instances of ? corresponding to my 9 test projects, but how to execute those, or select  one or more to execute?

The fluent syntax is preferrable, just cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer: I'm pretty new to nuke.*

I'm afraid VSTest really only accepts paths to DLL files. This is how I constructed the path:

```cs
Target Test => _ => _
    .DependsOn(Compile)
    .Executes(() => {
        var proj = Solution.GetProject("Tests");
        var outDir = proj.GetMSBuildProject(Configuration).GetPropertyValue("OutputPath");
        var assembly = proj.Directory / outDir / "Tests.dll";
        VSTest(assembly);
    });
```

It's still not pretty or convenient at all, but at least the hard-coded path is partially gone.

Also I'm not sure about the `net47` part in your path. I don't think its part of the `OutputPath` property. But `GetMSBuildProject()` takes a second optional parameter called `targetFramework` that could help with that.

Since you have multiple test projects you might find `SetTestAssemblies(IEnumerable<string>)` helpful:

```cs
VSTest(s => s.SetTestAssemblies(assemblies));
```